# Marshalling in Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

In [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/marshalling-directives/completeWith.html#completewith) link, the documentation uses instanceOf to marshal a object into JSON, as shown below:

```
val route = get {
  completeWith(instanceOf[Person]) { completionFunction => findPerson(completionFunction) }
}
```

However, when I try to use the same I get the error "`unable to resolve symbol instanceOf`". How can I fix this?

Comment: `import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. So is instanceOf a directive? But I am not able to find instanceOf under http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/alphabetically.html

Comment: Not a directive, more like a helper method. See https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/directives/MarshallingDirectives.scala

Comment: Thanks a ton! BTW, where can I read more about these helper methods? The documentation does not seem to directly talk about such helper methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you always `import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._` or extend directives like this in your class: `class MyRoutes extends Directives {`. This brings into scope everything you need.

We'll work on samples to include all imports and link back to the source code so you can browse it in context in the near future.